# Removing options fom Select using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, select

```
<select>
    <option value="Value 1">Apple</option>
    <option value="Value 2">Mango</option>
    <option value="Value 3">Grape</option>
    <option value="Value 4">Banana</option>
</select>
```

And I have String "Grape" and the result output should be like this.

```
<select>
    <option value="Value 1">Apple</option>
    <option value="Value 2">Mango</option>
    <option value="Value 4">Banana</option>
</select>
```

How to do that?

Comment: Have you tried anything before posting here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use the [jQuery `:contains()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) -

> **`:contains()`** - Select all elements that contain the specified text.

For example:

```
var txt = "Grape";
var element = $( "#selectElement option:contains('"+ txt +"')" );
element.remove(); // now just remove it
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)** selector and [**remove**](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) function.

```
$('select option:contains(Grape)').remove();
```

[**Working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/PAMUn/)

**Note:** It is better if you give an `ID` to your `select` element.

Answer (score 0):

give your **select an id(unique)** , use id selector to get the select element. and use `:contains` selector

```
$(function(){ 
  $('#givenSelectID option:contains("Grape")').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the Js fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/CZL2y/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var txt = "Grape";
var element = $( "select option:contains('"+ txt +"')" );
element.remove();
});
```